# What is the Haskell reverse function expected in this code?

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, type-mismatch, function-call

I'm writing a small Haskell exercise, it is should shift some elements within a list, similar to a Caesar cipher, the code is already working, the code is below.

```
module Lib (shift, cipherEncode, cipherDecode ) where
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

abcdata :: [Char]
abcdata = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

iabcdata :: [Char]
iabcdata = ['g','f','e','d','c','b','a']

shift :: Char -> Int -> Char
shift l n = if (n >= 0)
            then normalShift l n
            else inverseShift l (abs n)

normalShift :: Char -> Int -> Char
normalShift l n = shifter l n abcdata

inverseShift :: Char -> Int -> Char
inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse(abcdata) -- This is the line

charIdx :: Char -> [Char] -> Int
charIdx target xs = fromJust $ elemIndex target xs

shifter :: Char -> Int -> [Char] -> Char
shifter l n xs = if (n < length (xs))
            then
                picker ((charIdx l xs) + n) xs
            else
                picker ((charIdx l xs) + (n `mod` length (xs))) xs

picker :: Int -> [Char] -> Char
picker n xs = if n < length xs
              then
                xs!!n
              else
                xs!!(n `mod` length (xs))
```

The question I have is regarding the line

`inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse(abcdata)`

If I change it by

`inverseShift l n = shifter l n iabcdata`

it works fine

also, when I do `reverse(abcdata) == iabcdata` it is `True`
but when I leave the `reverse` in the code I get the following error

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> Char'
                  with actual type `Char'
    * The function `shifter' is applied to four arguments,
      but its type `Char -> Int -> [Char] -> Char' has only three
      In the expression: shifter l n reverse (abcdata)
      In an equation for `inverseShift':
          inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse (abcdata)
   |
21 | inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse(abcdata)
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    * Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
                  with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    * Probable cause: `reverse' is applied to too few arguments
```

What am I doing wrong by calling `shifter` with `reverse(abcdata)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how parentheses work in Haskell. The way you wrote it, `reverse` and `abcdata` would both be arguments to `shifter`, but you want `abcdata` to be an argument to `reverse`. Do `shifter l n (reverse abcdata)` instead of `shifter l n reverse(abcdata)`.

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong by calling `shifter` with `reverse(abcdata)` ?

The answer *is* in the message:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> Char'
                  with actual type `Char'
    * The function `shifter' is applied to four arguments,
      but its type `Char -> Int -> [Char] -> Char' has only three
      In the expression: shifter l n reverse (abcdata)
      In an equation for `inverseShift':
          inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse (abcdata)
```

Repeat,

#### `` In an equation for `inverseShift': ``

## `inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse (abcdata)`
                                               `~~~~~~~~~~~~~   -- mind the gap!`

*That* is how your expression was read by Haskell. And *this* is how it was written by you:

```
   |
21 | inverseShift l n = shifter l n reverse(abcdata)
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So you haven't in fact called `shifter` with `reverse(abcdata)`.

You called it with `reverse` *and* `(abcdata)` (as well `l` and `n`), as is also explained in the other answer.